# Pass data between component in Angular

Tags: angular

I have this page structure

[image]

> app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I load all data in `app.component.ts` file using shared service

```
import { Component,HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TokenService } from './shared/token.service';
import { AuthStateService } from './shared/auth-state.service';
import { SharedData,SharedService } from './shared/shared-service.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;
  homePageTitle:any;
  title:any;
  ...
  data: SharedData;


  constructor(
    private auth: AuthStateService,
    public router: Router,
    public token: TokenService,
    private http: HttpClient, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'api/content').subscribe(result  => {
      this.title=result['response'].title;
      ... 
      ...
     this.setData();
    });
    
  }

  setData(): void {
 this.sharedService.setData({title: this.title,....});
      this.sharedService.sharedData.subscribe(result => this.data = result);
  }
}
```

> shared-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export interface SharedData {
  title: any;
  ...

}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SharedService  {

  private sharedData$ = new BehaviorSubject<SharedData>({title: '',...other fields});
  sharedData = this.sharedData$.asObservable();

  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  setData(data: SharedData): void {
    this.sharedData$.next(data);
  }
}
```

when i subscribe to this service in `footer,header and home component` i get blank data in all the fields.

`this.sharedService.sharedData.subscribe(result => this.data = result);`

[image]

Comment: One of the greatest advantages of Angular is its documentation. You can find all the answers that you need [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0xBobby's answer works fine with parent-child components but in more complex scenarios (with routing, for example) I would recommend using a shared service and `BehaviorSubject` for communication between components. Chech this Stackblitz example based loosely on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbus9x?file=src/app/app.component.ts.

First, you create a SharedService used to, well, share data between components:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

  private sharedData$ = new BehaviorSubject<SharedData>({title: '', logo: ''});
  sharedData = this.sharedData$.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setData(data: SharedData): void {
    this.sharedData$.next(data);
  }
```

The in the HomeComponent you set the data you want to share:

```
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}

  setData(): void {
    this.sharedService.setData({title: this.title, logo: this.logo});
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'api/content').subscribe(result  => {
        this.title=result.title;
        this.logo=result.logo;
        this.setData();
    });
  }
```

and finally you subscribe to the the observable in AppComponent and FooterComponent where you want to show the same data:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  
  data: SharedData;

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedService.sharedData.subscribe(result => this.data = result);
  }
  
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that the communication works between deeply nested components, with routed componentes, with services, etc.

Comment: Thanks i tried this but when i access the data in other component like footer then the data is blank

Comment: You put the call to the sharedService.setData in the Home component where you get the data from the API.

Comment: Check the updated HomeComponent code in my answer above.

Comment: I have updated my code in my question can you please check

Comment: Where do you subscribe to the sharedService.sharedData? In Header, Home and Footer component's ngOnInit? Does your API return data?

Comment: Yes api is returning data initially i set all the data retuned from api call in `app.component` then subscribe to `sharedService.sharedData` in `home.component`, `footer.component` and `header.component`

Comment: Sorry, without seeing more details of your code I don't think I can help you. Check the Stackblitz in my answer. You could fork it and adapt it more closely to your case.

Comment: Issue is when i put this `this.sharedService.setData({title: this.Title, logo: '341'});` inside subscribe method where i fetch the value then the values are blank when i put this code outside that subscribe method and assign static value then the data are being shared between components

Comment: Could you, please, update your question with an example of the working code with static values and with code that's not working. As you describe it in your comment, the API call is either not called or doesn't return data.

Comment: Is this issue related to async issue because as you can see in screenshot in the above question `Home component` is being called before the `app component`, and when i i have copied the stackblitz code and for static data it is working

Comment: It looks like you have errors in your code that are not related to the original question.

Comment: yes there is one error but in this case  home component is getting called first then app. Component is called that's why the data is blank data is set in app.component

Comment: If done correctly, the order of the calls doesn't matter. Every component simply waits for the service to emit new values. I would try to fix the errors first because it could be possible that some methods are not called at all because of the errors that are thrown.

Comment: Is there any other way, in my case no other component will update that data is it possible to fetch all the data from service file and call that service file from footer and subscribe it in other component

Comment: It doesn't matter where you fetch the data. After fetching it you call the sharedService.setData(data) method and all other components that subscribe to the sharedService.sharedData will get a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data between components that have a parent-child relationship by using `@Input` decorator.

1. Go into `footer.component.ts` and add

```
@Input() 
data: {title: string, logo: string};
```

2. Save the data inside `home.component.ts` into a single object:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
      this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'api/content').subscribe(result  => {
        this.footerData = {title: result.title, logo: result.logo};
      });
  }
```

3. Make sure you pass in the input. In `home.component.html`

```
<app-footer [data]="footerData"></app-footer>
```

Alternatively you can declare multiple `@Input` members in footer, one for each property.

Comment: Thanks how will i pass data from `home component` to `app.component` do i have to set `app.component` parent component and pass data from `app.component` to `home.component` then from `home.component` to `footer.component`?