# Manage Parent child relationship in Angular layout

Tags: angular

I have this `app.component.html`

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-home [Titleheader]="Title" *ngIf="router.url == '/'"></app-home> 
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

`app-home` component is my home page that should only be visible on `/home` and `/` url

this is my route file

```
const routes: Routes = [
  
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' },
];
```

when i add `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },` this to route only home page is visible  removing this route redirects me to `404` not found. But i want complete home page when i access `/` or `/home` url.

> Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export interface SharedData {
  title: string;
  logo: string;
  gallery:array......
}
export class SharedServiceService {
  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  setData() {

    this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'api/content').subscribe(result  => {

      console.log('result');
     
    });
  }
}
```

Any Solution Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '/', component: AppHomeComponent},
{ path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
{ path: '/home', redirectTo: '/' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' },
];

<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

You have to do the home page redirection throw the route so do like this it will work

Comment: Thanks if i declare these components inside `<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet><app-footer></app-footer>` app.component then i will not be able to pass data which i fetch on `app.component` on pageload using @input Directive because here all the components are related

Comment: if you want to pass data using input output then you cant use the separate route in should be a single page application

Comment: or you have to pass data using observable

Comment: can you please let me know how we can achieve the same results through service,i have updated my code in question

Comment: I explained you how to user services in the other question you posted yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72364564/pass-data-between-component-in-angular